# Bootstrap navigation, long link going on two lines in IE, fine in others. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently creating a responsive site and it is using *bootstrap*. The nav buttons at the top are fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox but in IE the one which states `Public Consultation` is running on to two lines.

I think that this is because the CSS is tying to make them equal when I ideally don't need them equal, I just want them to run across the page in one line full container width with a divider between each one.

Not sure what is causing it. I can see padding of 15 top and bottom of the words and 2px right and left but not sure why it won't all run on one line in IE.

Link to it here: http://www.shineinternet.co.uk/demos/links/links.htm

Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: You can force the links not to wrap the text by adding the following css to `.nav-justified > li > a {white-space: nowrap;}`

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. That did the trick, http://www.shineinternet.co.uk/demos/links/links.htm although on IE the words Public Consultation are quite tight to the lines. Any way around this?

Comment: You could override the left and right padding for the links, they are now at 2px which is kind of too little, so why not increase them `.nav-justified > li > a {padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;}`

Answer (score 0):

You could try

`white-space:no-wrap`
on the nav elements, which is IE8+